# Can Ghidra load a directory and translate the binary files within it into assembly code?

Tags: ida, ghidra, objdump

Can Ghidra load a directory and automatically convert the binary files within it into assembly code? If not, is there a pre-defined script available, or do I need to write one myself? If Ghidra isn't suitable, do you recommend any other tools for this task besides objdump and IDA?